# iOS background fetch time limit crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, background-process

I've set up background fetch, using outline from [NSScreencast episode #92](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/92-background-fetch).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  ...
  [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
  ...
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler 
{
    if ([[MyAppAPIClient manager] reachable] && [[Session manager] userSignedIn])
    {
        [[[Session manager] user] fetchBackgroundWithSuccess:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSDictionary *responseObject) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
        } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultFailed);
        }];
    }
    else
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

For the `fetchBackgroundWithSuccess:failure` method, I'm using AFNetworking `NSURLSessionDataTask`.

Unfortunately, sometimes I get the error

```
MyApp[3344] has active assertions beyond permitted time:
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x178279c00> identifier: Background Content Fetching (1596) process: MyApp[3344] permittedBackgroundDuration: 30.000000 reason: backgroundContentFetching owner pid:16 preventSuspend      preventThrottleDownUI  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

and it completely crashes my app, logs out my user, and all of the user's data is wiped clean.

Not sure how to fix this, but any direction would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

The way I store data is using NSKeyedArchiver's `archiveRootObject:toFile` and `unarchiveObjectWithFile`. It keeps track if the user is logged in, their user_id, and other important info. This is all cached in memory using a singleton object of class `User`.

`archiveRootObject:toFile` is called during

1. `applicationWillResignActive`
2. `applicationDidEnterBackground`
3. `applicationWillTerminate`
4. `applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning`

`unarchiveObjectWithFile` is called as needed if the singleton is nil.

So logged out and wiped clean means the singleton is nil and `unarchiveObjectWithFile` fails to retrieve any data.

Comment: Can you clarify *exactly* what you mean by 'logs out my user, and all the user's data is wiped clean.'

Comment: Let me know if the update above isn't sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Every background fetch has a time limit, which is I believe 30 seconds. Unlike a normal background task that can utilize an expiration handler to automatically clean up and do what you need to do when you run out of time, background fetches currently don't have that ability. One way you can handle this is perhaps start an NSTimer that is scheduled to go off something like 20-25 seconds into your background fetch, and have that timer call a function that handles if you haven't completed your background task to stop whatever you're doing and clean up everything so the app can go back to being backgrounded normally. From the docs:

> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of
>   wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the
>   specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call
>   the completion handler block as soon as possible after downloading the
>   needed data. ***If you do not call the completion handler in time, your
>   app is terminated.***

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:

The bold part sounds like that's exactly what's happening. Either way, you need to get done what you're trying to get done within the 30 seconds, otherwise you need to cancel it or your app will be terminated.

Comment: How would you do this in practice, though?

Comment: @Max Do what, exactly?

Comment: "start an NSTimer that is scheduled to go off something like 20-25 seconds into your background fetch, and have that timer call a function that handles if you haven't completed your background task to stop whatever you're doing and clean up everything"  Cheers

Comment: I think that is fairly self explanatory. What part of that do you need help with?

Comment: It's definitely a good explanation, but some code would really help beef up the answer considering how many times its been viewed. The timer should be easy enough, but how would you "stop whatever you're doing" using code?

Comment: Completely depends what you're doing. If you simply call the completion handler your application will stop background execution without crashing it. If you're doing some async tasks or something else that needs time to finish that needs to be handled on a case-by-case basis, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

This question is kind of old but maybe the following code can help some developers that are interested in a code snippet based on Mike´s answer. As Mike suggested I also use a NSTimer to cancel the background fetch when it takes too much time. In my background fetch I access my webservice with AFNetworking to grab some new data. If the time (I chose 25 seconds) is up I simply cancel all my open requests to the webservice in the NSOperationQueue. Here´s my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    // This Handler accesses my webservice using AFNetworking and creates NSOperationQueue to enqueue the requests
    backgroundSearchHandler = BackgroundFetchSearchHandler()

    let cancelTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(25, target: self, selector: "cancelBackgroundFetch", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    backgroundSearchHandler!.findNewResultsForSavedSearches { (completed, newResultCount) -> Void in

        // This block is also called when the timer is over and the requests were cancelled

        // Stop the timer
        cancelTimer.invalidate()

        if !completed
        {
            completionHandler(.Failed)
            return
        }

        if newResultCount <= 0
        {
            completionHandler(.NoData)
            return
        }

        completionHandler(.NewData)
    }
}

func cancelBackgroundFetch()
{
    backgroundSearchHandler?.cancel()
    // This is calling cancelAllOperations() on the NSOperationQueue in my background search handler
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is BackgroundFetchSearchHandler here ?

Comment: @SolidSoft: As I wrote in the comment above it: "This Handler accesses my webservice using AFNetworking and creates NSOperationQueue to enqueue the requests". What the handler does exactly is not relevant for this example. The handler can just complete and thus end the background fetch (.NoData or .NewData) or it can be canceled when the timer fires because it took too long (.Failed) You can replace it by anything that is cancelable and has a similar completion structure. The limit is your creativity ;-)